# How to open two project windows side by side in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am an absolute beginner in Illustrator. I am following an udemy tutorial. I have the following two project windows -

[image]

[image]

Now, I am unable to follow the tutorial and open the project windows side by side.

This is my options bar -

[image]

In the region marked with a question mark, the author of the lecture has an option for the split window. But in my illustrator, the option is not there.

I am using the same "essentials classic" workspace as the author.

I am using Microsoft Windows 11 Operating System

This is what the author's illustrator window looks like -

[image]

Notice the options of the red circled area which is not present in my illustrator.

Comment: Drag the tabs out then you can arrange them again?

Comment: It works but why the split option like the author is not in my illustrator? Plus author is also able to flawlessly drag artworks from one project window to another, but with your solution it is not happening

Comment: You can't split tabs, you need floating windows - hence the suggestion to drag them down out of the tab bar.

Comment: Are you suere he just does not have 2 arboards in the same document

Comment: Yes I am sure, it is a split view, two project windows side by side, art soft copied from the artboard of one window to artboard of another window by drag and drop

Comment: @Tetsujin updated my question with author's window's screenshot

Comment: ah - it's in the Window menu, idk how to put it on the toolbar. I had brain fog, I never tile. You can tile tabs, my bad.

Comment: @Tetsujin So you are saying that without this functionality I will do just fine?

Comment: It's just in a slightly different place on Windows computers. [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/eeIHfyG) - might also depend what version of Illustrator you have. The screenshot is CC 2018 on a Win 10 pc.  I don't know if they've changed it on later versions.

Comment: You should also be able to do *Windows > Arrange > Tile* in older versions.

Comment: I am using licensed version and as such it is the latest @BillyKerr

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you so much, please consider putting it as answer

Comment: @PayelSenapati - I've added it as an answer now.

Comment: Note that answer by @BillyKerr is the same as pulling out tab and arranging it yourself. Its just that the newer version no longer allows you to stack them this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in a different position on Windows computers. The screenshot you are showing is Mac.

Here's a screenshot of Illustrator CC 2018 on Win 10, not the latest version (which may have changed). Adobe changes the user interface from version to version, so I often loose track.

[image]

You should also be able to get the same view by doing *Windows > Arrange > Tile*

Answer (score 0):

open both projects you're currently working in adobe illustrator, and drag out the tap, readjust them and press Ctrl+0 to set the tap content to the center and then you can start to edit your project freely side by side.